# Where is the policy to control DHCP access?

Tags: group-policy

The client created a group policy to meet  Payment Card Industry (`PCI`). Now, they have a problem to access the `DHCP` server as shown the screenshot.

[image]

I have reviewed all policies' settings, but can't find which one is applied to deny accessing `DHCP`. When using administrator account to open `DHCP`, it does ask for the credentials. After I enter correct credentials, above screen shows with a red stop sign. Where is the policy to control `DHCP` access?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a specific Group Policy setting to restrict or grant access to the DHCP management console or DHCP server role. My suggestion would be to remove/unlink the offending GPO and review the settings to see what is preventing access to DHCP while the policy is being applied. It may be a group membership issue or a user rights issue.

Comment: If you're trying to manage the DHCP server from a separate machine, there might be a firewall rule blocking access.

Comment: I am not sure this causes by the group policy. I do know after they configured the group policy, you need to enter credentials to open DNS, ADUC, Server Manager and event Viewer. I assume it is something to do with the group policy. DHCP seems to work because the we can renew the IP address. The problem is we can't open it with a red stop sign. I may try to export the DHCP and re-configure it.